# FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR Value of class java.lang.Boolean is not a ValueType: ANYTYPE FlowScreen Search_Params

Tags: managed-package, screen-flow, namespace

I have a screen flow that, after some parameters to define on the first screen, makes a call to a controller that makes a callout to an external REST service and then returns the result to the flow.

Everything works well when I execute my flow in a scratch org or dev org with the same namespace and deployed with sfdx.

But when I build a managed package, install it on a partner entreprise org and execute my flow, my flow starts but fails at the step of calling the external API.

As I'm running a managed package, I don't have my execution logs.
I only have the following error:

```
FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR Value of class java.lang.Boolean is not a ValueType: ANYTYPE|FlowScreen|Search_Params
```

Does anyone know what this error means?

For information, Search_Params is the id of my first screen composed of a select box with 2 possible values and depending on the value selected, a text field is displayed for filling the appropriate information.

I have no boolean in this screen.

The only boolean that exists in my flow is the boolean returned by my controller for success information.

Is it something about my package namespace as in case or scratch/dev orgs, they have the same namespace that my package, to the contrary of the target case, where my namespaced package is installed inside a lambda enterprise org without namespace?

Even if you don't the answer, any hint or suggestion can help me!

Thank you,
Fabrice